# How do I derive the frequency of oscillation of the capacitor voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, frequency, inductance

The formula is $$\omega= \frac{1}{\sqrt{L \times C}}.$$ How do I derive this?

Comment: Read for example [LC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit).

Comment: You have to understand what differential equation the voltage satisfies. It will have an oscillatory solution with this angular frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is for the resonant frequency of a series LC circuit. Resonance occurs when the capacitive and inductive reactances are equal. Set the capacitive reactance equal to the inductive reactance and solve for ω.

Hope this helps.